# Replicate record in a DataTable based on value of a column using C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a record in a dataTable as shown below.

```
1  Test   7Dec2014   15:40   one,two,three
```

Since the last column has 3 comma separated values, the resultant `DataTable` should like below with replicated records.

```
1 Test 7Dec2014 15:40 one
2 Test 7Dec2014 15:40 two
3 Test 7Dec2014 15:40 three
```

Please help me with an optimized way to achieve the above result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimized way I found for the above problem is as below. If anybody has a better solution please let me know.

```
    string[] strValues;
    for (int i = 0; i < dtTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        strValues= dtTable.Rows[i]["Column_Name"].ToString().Split(',');
        if (strValues.Length > 1)
        {
            dtTable.Rows[i]["Column_Name"] = strValues[0];
            for (int j = 1; j < strValues.Length; j++)
            {
                var TargetRow = dtTable.NewRow();
                var OriginalRow = dtTable.Rows[i];
                TargetRow.ItemArray = OriginalRow.ItemArray.Clone() as object[];
                TargetRow["Column_Name"] = strValues[j];
                dtTable.Rows.Add(TargetRow);
            }
        }
    }
```